405 Method Not Allowed - strict-origin-when-cross-origin IIS8
I do web design, I don't know a lot about web servers beyond basics.
I am using Joomla 4 and Yootheme Pro 4 on an IIS 8.5 server. When I try to delete items fro "My Layouts" they don't get deleted.
When I use the browser inspector I get the errors below.
405 Method Not Allowed
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

DELETE https://www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_ajax&p=builder%2Flibrary&templateStyle=14&id=INFrqvsK 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous)             @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:3
rA                  @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:3
fetch                   @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:4
delete                  @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:4
deleteElement           @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:135
q                   @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:166
Promise.then (async)        
b                   @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:166
e.trigger           @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:166
installed.e.$trigger    @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:166
deleteElement           @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:118
click                   @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:118
(anonymous)         @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:109
await in (anonymous) (async)        
Rn                  @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:3
r                   @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:3
Ex.o.\_wrapper          @   customizer.min.js?4.3.13:3

My web.config file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="Joomla! Common Exploits Prevention" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\)" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(>|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(&lt;|%3E)" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="CustomResponse" url="index.php" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="Joomla! API Application SEF URLs">
                   <match url="^api/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/api/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="api/index.php" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="Joomla! Public Frontend SEF URLs">
                   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                     <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>


        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="php-8.1.12" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-8.1.12-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="PHPHTML" path="*.html" verb="*" type="" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-8.1.12-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="bitness32" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" type="" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="Content-Security-Policy" />
                <remove name="EXPECT-CT" />
                <remove name="Permissions-Policy" />
                <remove name="Referrer-Policy" />
                <remove name="Strict-Transport-Security" />
                <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
                <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <remove extension=".png, .jpg, .svg" />
                <add extension=".jpg, .png, .svg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>

Handler mappings
I have read quite a few threads on here and other websites, but I don;t know what to add/delete/change.
I tried suggestions from this page with no change - 405 Method not allowed error in angularjs http Post request with IIS 8.5.

Try using failed request tracing to see details about 405 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

I don't know IIS very well and am a little worried about messing something up, but I tried following some directions to do this. But, in the failed request tracing rules I don't have a redirect option to check and am not getting a log. I do have rewrites that work, so it is installed.

Does this answer your question? IIS 7.5 + enable PUT and DELETE for RESTFul service, extensionless

I seem to have gotten it to work. Using information on this page I did the below. I don't know if it is the right or best way, but it seems to have fixed my problem.
In IIS Manager, under handler mappings, I changed PHP request restrictions/verbs to all verbs.
Then, in my web.config file, I added this:
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>

